# Android Studio 2.0: Why does Instant Run not work when modifying xml layout resources?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is a very new feature, as Android Studio 2.0 is only available in the canary release channel, however I was hoping someone could further explain how the Instant Run feature works.

If I modify code within my Java classes (Activities, Fragments, etc.) then Instant Run works smoothly. It keeps the instance of the app running and swaps out code behind the scenes, greatly improving the time it takes for me to test (which is awesome, btw).

However, if I **modify existing layout xml resources**, then it has to **recompile a build and deploy it**. So my questions are:

1. Why does it need to rebuild when modifying existing layout xml resources?
2. Are there plans for the future to allow hot-swapping XML resources so that I don't have to rebuild every time I want to see a change in layout? (Although, I know I can just view changes in the Design view).

Question #1 is more important to me at the moment, because I'd like to understand how it all works.
Also, congratulations to the Android Studio team. The IDE has come a long way. The performance improvements are life-changing.

Comment: "Why does it need to rebuild when modifying existing layout xml resources?" -- probably `R` class changes. From their presentations, it sounded like not every change would necessarily do a full rebuild. The Android Developer Summit is going on now; you will want to watch the videos from today's sessions as they become available on YouTube, where a number of these sorts of details are discussed, at least to a limited level. "Are there plans" sorts of questions and "congratulations" are best directed to Google; Stack Overflow is not Google.

Comment: This is just a guess, but might it have to do something with how the resource files work? Basically, the XML file is translated into a Java file at build time. Which is why old version of the IDE needed the whole "clean" step whenever we made changes to the XML files.

Comment: I think we should wait till the final version gets release... preview versions always are full of bugs and we don't know if that one is one of those. Also, as @CommonsWare say, probably `R` changes.

Comment: I just tried this with both situations you described (modifying Java code and modifying XML layouts) and it appeared to deploy it the same way for both. (Both cases I tried were very simple. Changing the background color of an activity, and adding a toast message. On a clean project)

Comment: @CommonsWare, I realize Stack Overflow is not Google, but you'd be surprised at the number of Google Developer Advocates who are active on Stack Overflow. And I do agree that it's sort of premature to ask this question, but I was just too curious to wait around for video lectures on it. Also, it's well worth opening it up for discussion amongst others, since I know we're all super excited about it.

Comment: @AndrewBrooke hmmm, I'll have to try it out with a clean project later I suppose. I'm trying it out with an existing project, so maybe something funky is going on, but noone's to blame there since it's such a new release. This stuff is expected. I just wanted to open it up for discussion.

Comment: @w3bshark, definitely. In any case, its a great feature, and I'm looking forward to using it in my projects.

Comment: For me this makes it almost imposible to work since my project has several libraries e.g. a UI lib. Everytime I want to test something I have to wait ~2 minutes for the complete rebuild...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[image]

As you know all the resources used in your xml file are converted into static fields in R class. As per the information got from http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run changing static fields are not supported by instant Run.

Comment: At least for now... Adding or removing fields is currently an incompatible change which requires a full rebuild, but Google is working on fixing that. By the time 2.0 hits the stable channel modifying fields will probably also be a hot-swappable.

Answer (score 5):

Just a little hint. When I switched from Android Studio 1.5 to 2.0 (stable) the new Instant Run didn't work with layout changes.
I tried `Run` > `Clean and rerun app` and I solved, since that moment Instant Run works.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Google launches **[Android Studio 2.0 beta](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest)** with Cold Swap, app indexing improvements, and multi-touch support.