# Isn't the instant run feature in Android Studio working properly?

Tags: android-studio, android-instant-run

I've was excited that they added the instant run feature.
As I mentioned, this feature isn't working as it should.

Sometimes it don't apply changes and it makes hard to debug!

Is something to check/uncheck or change the settings to make it work properly?

Kind Regards.

Comment: for which `code` `Instant run feature` not properly work can you specified.

Comment: It doesn't matter. It's not working with every code

Comment: are you using `Android Studio 2.0` ?

Comment: visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902467/android-studio-2-0-why-does-instant-run-not-work-when-modifying-xml-layout-reso

Comment: not all code change are supporeted by `Instant run` see the upper link.