# How to Run app in Android Studio without kill and restart the session?

Tags: android, android-studio

At this point, Im using Android Studio 2.1.2. When I changed the code or without changed the code, the app is always kill and restart the session when I want to run the app.
[Run App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EilL.png)

So how to run the app without kill and restart the session?

Comment: i have the same when i compile an app who already have the same package on the phone, are you sure ure phone is correclty linked to your computer?

Comment: The new update allows us to _hotswap_ changes.

Comment: Update Android studio to 2.0 + there you have Instant run feature...

Comment: ya my phone is correclty linked to my computer, it already tested with my another android project, it was runnning well. Nah when I opened the another android project and I want to run this new one, Android studio is always kill and restart the session. Any solution please? @JulienGenoud

Comment: Im using Android Studio 2.1.2. But it still doesn't work. Any solution? @Arpan @ Ram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wondering about Instant Run facility added in most latest versions of android studio. To use it please Make sure you have up to date Gradle plug-ins and builds because it's not only enough that having latest version of Android studio will support Instant Run it also required all stuff up-to-date so Please first check it out.

To check it out if it is disable follow this steps

1) Go to File -> Settings 
2) Go to Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run

By default It is enabled if everything is up to date. If not you can.

[image]

Go read this for depth understanding :
 https://medium.com/google-developers/instant-run-how-does-it-work-294a1633367f#.mqwx46kn6

And what is supported under instant run is given here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33905037/5476209

Comment: The issue with Instant run can be raised, if they have any conflict with multidex files, ex. say you have a class which was parsed and compiled in one of the dex file! now you have made some changes and due to that a new dex file was created in the sequence! Here Instant run will create and append new dex file in the sequence and run the app!... BUT when some part of your application is trying to parse the old dex files, the calls will not be found over there because it has been moved to new dex and all the dex files haven't been synced with each line of code ...

Comment: Even though app was run successfully , but that was for particular part only ... not for whole app.... so while you are testing your whole app you should avoid `Instant run`... this happens in very rare cases in context of java coding only!!! But about the xml designing I haven't seen such issue till now ... `Must read this -> https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#ir-limitations` ... Correct me if I'm wrong anywhere ...

Answer (score 0):

You need the latest Gradle build in your project for the same And also you need to run the same app in your phone so that the patch will be installed and activity will be restarted.
Please not that every time you hit an error in run time the quick launch will get disabled and you will have to rebuild the whole project to Instant run again.
Reference :http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run